# Java MySQL IndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

Why am I getting this error:

java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4 , Size: 4

I am not defining anything and have used the same logic on another servlet that is working fine. In my other servlet I am selecting all products, so I used two arraylists: one inside the other. I tried that here but still have the same error. I clearly understand the error but I have no idea how to resolve it in this syntax.

Thank you.

```
ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

int product_id =Integer.parseInt(req.substring(req.lastIndexOf("/")+1));  

ArrayList al = null;
String query = "select * from Product where product_id="+product_id;

try {
    ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = ps.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs.next()) {
        al = new ArrayList();

        al.add(rs.getString("product_id"));
        al.add(rs.getString("product_name"));
        al.add(rs.getString("product_description"));
        al.add(rs.getDouble("product_price"));
    }
```

The next JSP page from this servlet is:

```
    <%! 
        String product_id=""; 
        String product_name=""; 
        String product_description=""; 
        double product_price = 0; 
    ArrayList  productList=null; 
    %> 

    <% 
    if(request.getAttribute("productList")!=null && request.getAttribute("productList")!="") { 
        productList = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("productList"); 
        product_id = productList.get(1).toString(); 
        product_name = productList.get(2).toString(); 
        product_description = productList.get(3).toString(); 
        product_price = (Double) productList.get(4);
    } 
    %>
```

Comment: Probably `req` ends with a `/`, so that `req.substring(req.lastIndexOf("/")+1)`gives an error.

Comment: Could you please post a stacktrace?

Comment: Puzzling exceptions are often much clearer if you no what line throws them. So you should not just log he message but also at least the line of the last stack trace entry.

Comment: a) Move your code out of the jsp into a proper java class.
b) The exception is not thrown in the code block you are showing us. Probably there is some jsp tag where you are trying to get al[4].

Comment: you might be right, posted above the next jsp page taking this stuff

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you possibly are getting that exception on this line

```
int product_id =Integer.parseInt(req.substring(req.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

from your code, this could be the only case. when you call subString() on req index is going out of bound. the best test would be to put a sysout the length of req

**EDIT AFTER POSTING THE STACKTRACE**

change your java code to this
          al = new ArrayList();
     while (rs.next()) {
        al.add(rs.getString("product_id")); // stored in the al at index 0
        al.add(rs.getString("product_name"));// stored in the al at index 1
        al.add(rs.getString("product_description"));// stored in the al at index 2
        al.add(rs.getDouble("product_price"));// stored in the al at index 3
    }

heres where its throwing the exception

```
 line1:  product_id = productList.get(1).toString(); 
 line2:               product_name = productList.get(2).toString(); 
 line3:               product_description = productList.get(3).toString(); 
 line4               product_price = (Double) productList.get(4); /// its going indexoutfbound    here
```

your list has only 4 elements and you are trying to get the 5th element with above code. 
     }

change them to

```
  product_id = productList.get(0).toString(); 
                product_name = productList.get(1).toString(); 
                product_description = productList.get(2).toString(); 
                product_price = (Double) productList.get(3);
}
```

Comment: but the same thing is working in the other servlet , both coming from the same jsp page through a javascript -  function editRecord(product_id){ 
    
    window.location.href="/Store/SelectProduct/"+product_id;  
  } 
 
 
  function deleteRecord(product_id){ 
    
    window.location.href="/Store/DeleteProduct/"+product_id;  
  }

Comment: can you post the stacktrace please

Comment: am doing it but getting another erorr, am going to post my whole servlet and view to be clearer and the new stacktrace, i will edit the question to a neater version after its resolved, thanks for the effort btw am so grateful to you and everyone

Comment: i guess the code is pretty much this, so makes no difference to post more, i will post the new trace

Comment: well, here's part of it An error occurred at line: 35 in the jsp file: /admin/editproduct.jsp
Syntax error, insert "Finally" to complete TryStatement
32:                 product_description = productList.get(2).toString(); 
33:                 product_price = (Double) productList.get(3);
34: } 
35: } 
36: %> 
37:  
38: <form name="productform" method="post" action="/EditProduct"> 


An error occurred at line: 138 in the generated java file
Syntax error on token "catch", Identifier expected

An error occurred at line: 140 in the generated java file
out cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan if you are wrapping code around try/catch. it is probably missing a brace. can you repost your jsp file in your question(not here in comments) with neat formatting ..

Comment: thank you for the help it works now , i will refubrish the question an d make it clear

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan  can you please also accept the most acceptable answer if you are satisfied with one

Comment: can someone please give me a rating or something so I can start choosing answers or rating you guys and everyone for the help you

Answer (score 3):

```
int product_id =Integer.parseInt(req.substring(req.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
```

If you had an url like so:
http://www.yahoo.com/

lastIndexOf will give you 21 and +1 gives 22 which is out of bounds.

**EDIT:**
After you pasted the servlet page I noticed that you seem to be confused on the index to access the arrayList. 
You start from 0 instead of 1 IIRC. So:

```
if(request.getAttribute("productList")!=null && request.getAttribute("productList")!="") 
    { 
                    productList = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("productList"); 
                    product_id = productList.get(1).toString(); 
                    product_name = productList.get(2).toString(); 
                    product_description = productList.get(3).toString(); 
                    product_price = (Double) productList.get(4);
    }
```

is

```
 if(request.getAttribute("productList")!=null && request.getAttribute("productList")!="") 
        { 
                        productList = (ArrayList)request.getAttribute("productList"); 
                        product_id = productList.get(0).toString(); 
                        product_name = productList.get(1).toString(); 
                        product_description = productList.get(2).toString(); 
                        product_price = (Double) productList.get(3);
        }
```

Comment: thank you, exactly the same notice from chaitanya10, i earlier when tried using 0 it was telling me it starts from 1 so i thought it's always 1, i will need to read about this now and learn.. thanks

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan Sure, np. Gl

Answer (score 0):

The error is giving is this:

```
**java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4**
 at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
 at org.apache.jsp.admin.editproduct_jsp._jspService(editproduct_jsp.java:82)
```

And is saying that it tried to get element number 5 (index=4) when the arraylist only had 4 elements. It seems that this stack trace is not an error of that code you are showing on your post. My guess is that error comes later when looping through the "a1" ArrayList which only has 4 elements and tried to get the fifth one.

Comment: kind of strange because this servlet simply goes to the edit page,nothing else is active

Answer (score -1):

```
while (rs.next()) {
        al = new ArrayList();

        al.add(rs.getString("product_id"));
        al.add(rs.getString("product_name"));
        al.add(rs.getString("product_description"));
        al.add(rs.getDouble("product_price"));
    }
```

you are initializing the arraylist inside the loop. That can be an issue too, if not, might make issues if that is not what you are expecting. The answer is given by others I guess

Comment: Why should that be an issue? That is totally unwarranted and only creates confusion.

Comment: tried to move the initialization here and there, still didn't help

Comment: this isn't the problem. y would this piece of code throw indexoutofbound.. check other answers

Comment: @DoubleMalt: That is why the word "Might" is used. If the OP is trying to put data into a single arraylist, then that is an error, in this case, because it makes lot of arraylists. If he/she need different arrayLists everytimes the loop runs, then no issue....However, I have clearly told the answer is given by others

Comment: @chaitanya10: it is allowed to give suggestions to users, to improve the code. Checking answers is up to the user, not up to us.

Comment: @Yohan tbh, the question isn't clear enough. the user should have posted the stacktrace along with the piece of code :)

Comment: @Yohan: As the comment of the OP shows, you succeeded in confusing him by speculating about possible problems, that are in no way indicated in the code or by the OP.

Comment: I posted it up there , hope it's the one